# How does this equation within a proof of subharmonic functions (PDEs) hold?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Im learning on PDE theory lectured in Evans's book, specifically Im trying to understand the proof, that if a function $v \in C^2$ is subharmonic, then $v(x) \leq \rlap{-}\!\!\int_{B_r(x)} v \, dy$ for any sphere $B_r(x) \subset U$ holds.

Within the proof there, is one equation that follows from [Green's first identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities):

\begin{align}
\rlap{-}\!\!\int_{\partial B_r(x)} \frac{d v(y)}{d \nu} \, dS(y) = \frac{r}{n} \rlap{-}\!\!\int_{B_r(x)} \triangle v(y) \, dy 
\end{align}

for a certain setting of parameters. If the volume of $B_r(x)$ corresponds to $\alpha(n)r^n$ and the surface of $\partial B_r(x)$ corresponds to $\alpha(n)r^{n-1}$, then obviously $\frac{r}{n}$ is derived from $ \frac{B_r(x)}{\partial B_r(x)}$; but where does this even occur in Green's first identity?

So my question is: why does this equation hold?

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure those integrals shouldn't be $\rlap{-}\!\!\int$ (for average) instead of $\int$?

Comment: Hi @DMcMor, thanks for your comment, yes Im sure those integrals are $\dashint$ (latex doesn't support this command on this site, so I wrote the constants simply infront of $\int$)

Comment: However I just saw you managed to build the command.. by which command? I would edit my question accordingly

Comment: I used `\rlap{-}\!\!\int`

Comment: @DMcMor thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in Evans, if I'm looking at the right place, is $$\rlap{-}\!\!\int_{\partial B_{r}(x)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\,dS(y) = \frac{r}{n}\rlap{-}\!\!\int_{B_{r}(x)}\Delta u(y)\,dy.$$

This follows from the first of Green's formulas, i.e. if $u,v \in C^{2}(\bar{U})$, then
$$\int_{U} \Delta u\,dx = \int_{\partial U}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\,dS.$$

Going back to the statement in question, then, we have
\begin{align}
\rlap{-}\!\!\int_{\partial B_{r}(x)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\,dS(y) &= \frac{1}{\left|\partial B_{r}(x)\right|}\int_{\partial B_{r}(x)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\,dS(y)\\
&=\frac{1}{\left|\partial B_{r}(x)\right|}\int_{B_{r}(x)}\Delta u(y)\,dy\\
&=\frac{\left|B_{r}(x)\right|}{\left|\partial B_{r}(x)\right|}\rlap{-}\!\!\int_{B_{r}(x)}\Delta u(y)\,dy\\
&=\frac{r}{n}\rlap{-}\!\!\int_{B_{r}(x)}\Delta u(y)\,dy.
\end{align}

So, at the end of the day we're basically multiplying by one for the sake of a nicer equation in terms of averages.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks @DMcMor, you know your stuff!